# Trying to Create a basic Text Based Game in Python. How can I implement an if loop around "Spear" without nesting

Tags: python-2.7, if-statement, for-loop, game-engine

I am trying to implement a loop around the option of having the spear or not.
With the spear, the hero should kill the bear. Without the spear, he should be eaten.

Originally, I set spear to False, and then changed it to TRUE when the hero picked up the spear. However, when looping back to bear_room(), the value of spear is reset to FALSE.

Is there any way to get around this without having to nest 2 if functions?
if not is there a cleaner implementation of the second if loop?

I attempted using if "true" and "true" and "if true and false" to determine whether the spear is held by the hero or not. Right now this does not work. However, the code still runs as is.

Here is the code:

```
    from sys import exit

    def dead(why):
        print why, "good Job!"
        exit(0)
    def bear_room():
        print """In front of you is a big bear. It stares at you. You notice a door behind the bear. To the side of the bear you see a spear propped up against the wall. What do you do?"""
        print"1. Fight the bear"
        print"2. Pick up the spear"
        print"3. try to run away"    
        bear = raw_input(">")
        spear = False
        if (bear == "1" and spear == True) :
            print "You fight and kill the bear"

        elif (bear == "1" and spear == False):
            dead("the bear claws your face off")

        elif (bear == "2" and spear == True):
            print "You already have the spear"
            bear_room()

        elif (bear == "2" and spear == False):
            print "you picked up the spear"
            spear = True
            print "Now do you want to fight the bear?"
            print "1. Fight the bear with the spear"
            print "2. Try to run away from the bear"
            choice = raw_input(">")
            if choice == "1":
                print """You fought and killed the bear, you can now
                go through the door"""
            elif choice == "2":
               dead("The bear eats you from behind")
            else:
                """You drop the spear, and retreat back to the entrance of  the room. """
                bear_room()

        elif (bear == "3"):
        dead("The Bear catches you and rips your head off")

        else:
            print "Please choose what to do!"
            bear_room()

    bear_room()
```

Answer (score 1):

declare `bear_room` with a parameter:

```
def bear_room(spear = False):
```

take out the initial `spear = False` and whenever you call recursively `bear_room` make sure you pass in `bear_room(spear)` to reflect if spear has been change.

Note that if you just call `bear_room()` with no parameters to pass in, `spear` will be reset to False

Answer (score 1):

Change the signature of the function `bear_room()` to `bear_room(spear_status=False)`
initialize your spear variable with  spear_status

and where ever you `calling bear_room()` call it as `bear_room(spear)`

Answer (score 0):

You can also make use of objects. Here is an example.

```
from sys import exit

class Person:
        def __init__(self, name):
                self.name = name
                self.items = []


        def die(self,why):
                print why, "good Job", self.name
                exit(0)

def bear_room(person):
        print """In front of you is a big bear. It stares at you. You notice a door behind the bear. To the side of the bear you see a spear propped up against the wall. What do you do?"""
        print"1. Fight the bear"

        has_spear = "Spear" in person.items
        if not has_spear: print"2. Pick up the spear"
        print  "3. try to run away"
        bear = raw_input(">")

        if (bear == "1" and has_spear) :
                print "You fight and kill the bear"
                return True

        elif (bear == "1" and not has_spear):
                person.die("the bear claws your face off")

        elif (bear == "2" and not has_spear):
                print "you picked up the spear"
                person.items.append("Spear")
                return False

        elif (bear == "3" and has_spear):
                person.die("The Bear catches you and rips your head off")

        elif (bear == "3" and not has_spear):
                person.die("The Bear eats you from behind")
        elif has_spear:
                print "You drop the spear retreat back to the entrance of  the room. "
                return True
        else:
            print "Please choose what to do!"
            return False


warrior = Person("Soldat")
while True:
    if bear_room(warrior): break
```